# Format phone number in UITextField with Rubymotion

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby, rubymotion

I am using Rubymotion to create an iOS application. I have a form and I am trying to format the UITextField. I know that I need to use the UITextFieldDelegate, and that functionality is working, but my formatting isn't formatting the field correctly. Please see my code below.

```
def textField(textField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange: range, replacementString: string)
  if textField == @phone
    location = range.location

    case location


    when 0..2
     p location

    when 3
     newString = NSString.stringWithFormat("(%)", @phone.text )
     @phone.text = newString


  end
end
```

end

Comment: Is the switch getting to 3? Are there any errors?

Comment: Try logging the string in each case `NSLog("%@", @phone.text)`

Comment: The switch is getting to 3. There aren't any errors and when I look at the log it prints to the console when i'm working and it shows the Format, but without the data in it, i.e. "()".

Comment: `NSString.stringWithFormat("(%@)", @phone.text )` might do the trick.

Comment: willrax, when I do that it formats it as follows ((null)). This at least throws a null value in there but still not the correct data.

Comment: Is there data in the `@phone.text`? Seems like there isn't an actual string there.

Comment: There is data in @phone.text, before I pass it into the NSSTring.stringWithFormat it shows the text, but when I put it in the method it throws a null. It clearly looks like the formatting of the method, but it looks correct by what everyone has put on this thread and also on the rubymotion api, and even Objective C API.

Comment: Try puts @phone.text before and after you format it to see if something is changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to put ()'s around the string this will work:

```
@phone.text = "(#{@phone.text})"
```

Or you can do this:

```
NSString.stringWithFormat("(%@)", @phone.text )
```

You can take a look at the formatters here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/articles/formatSpecifiers.html

The first example is just an interpolated string.